# Multiple new users linking to same service

Tags: support, answers, spam

Most of the answers they've posted only say go to `www.jsondata.com` but a few mention how it may be company employees posting these short answers. Are they applicable to be marked as spam if they all come from different users and it's somewhat relevant to the questions being asked?

Example from [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/how-can-i-retrieve-records-from-a-google-spreadsheet-in-json-format)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've deleted all posts mentioning jsondata.  In the future it is okay to flag these posts as spam. These do look promotional.

Good catch